# Error : out of memory

Tags: rendering

I have a model and when i press shit+z to render view or final render it gives and error out of memory. I tried on both cpu and gpu but the result is same error and stop there. How can i get rid of it and render my scene. Any suggestion or help to render.

**GPU mode**

[image]

**CPU mode**

[image]

[image]

When i open the file memory usage

[image]

Comment: As your models don't use that much ram I expect a modifier, material or simulation setting is causing cycles to want the excess ram. How large are the texture images you are using? Sharing your blend might help someone find the issue. [This site](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) is preferred for sharing blends.

Comment: @sambler i have attach some of the screen shot of my model no texture no simulation i have just material.

Comment: While blender says it is using 606MB for your scene, you only have 190MB free to use for rendering. Your task manager shows that you have 3409MB of total ram - you mention having 8GB. That appears to mean that you are running a 32bit version of windows which can only access 4GB of total ram, you will need a 64bit system to use the 8GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have the installed RAM for 8GB but you do not have 64-bit Windows software, you are using 32-bit software which restricts your system to below 4GB of usable RAM, to solve this issue you will need to render this on a 64-bit system so it can enough RAM to render. The reason the error occurs again with your graphics card is because it is only 2GB and also is below what the scene requires for rendering, remember that the RAM from your graphics card is separate from your desktop memory so it is not "extra" ram per se, you have these options:

1. Strip the scene back to the bare minimum so that your system can handle it
2. Upgrade your GPU to have higher VRAM which will support the render
3. Get 64-bit software to make use of the full 8GB of RAM which is installed

Answer (score 1):

Check that your computer has memory. Rendering something the computer needs some memory of the computer, I think. See at the top where it says Frame 1 Time: 00.05.35 etc? There you can see Mem.8.68M  - stands for memory (I think).

Comment: i have 8gb cup ram and 2gb graphic card

Answer (score 0):

A definitive way to clarify what is going on is to bring up Task Manager (Ctrl+Alt+Delete) then head to the performance tab where you will see hardware utilisation graphs, then you can just watch the Memory tab to see how much desktop memory the render is sucking up. For VRAM a secondary monitor (e.g. MSI Afterburner) can be used to see similar utilisation graphs and VRAM usage percentage. This method will clarify what is going on with your computer during the render. You have not shown your 3D view or scene here so I cannot offer too much beyond that, however, make sure your seen is not too heavy for your computer, is there many objects in the scene? Are you using many emission objects for lighting? Are there high-poly meshes being rendered? All these sorts of questions can reveal that the scene may be poorly optimised making it "heavy" i.e. a resource-intensive scene that will suck up much memory in order for it to be rendered. The last thing I will mention is that in File -> User Preferences -> Editing you can set the memory limit in blender to zero, this allows blender to use full memory out of your PC. First try and find out how your hardware is doing during the render, edit the settings and then work on optimising the scene for lower hardware. :)

Comment: I have attach my model image