# Estimating GPU memory requirements for rendering a scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am trying to render a scene with my NVIDIA GPU (4GB memory) but getting an error:

```
CUDA error Out of Memory in cuMemAlloc( device_pointer,mem.memory_size)
```

Most likely the heavy textures are to blame here, but I was wondering if I can estimate roughly what and by how much I need to cut down.

Is there a way to estimate the GPU memory requirements for a given scene?

Comment: reference https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89697/error-out-of-memory?noredirect=1#comment158171_89697